# Can these row test style unit tests be improved to follow good TDD design practices?

Tags: tdd, nunit, bdd, mspec, xunit

Can the following unittest be improved, to follow good TDD design practises (naming, using rowtests, designing the classes) in any of the .NET TDD/BDD frameworks?

Also, is there a better way in any of the frameworks to have rowtests where I can have a individual expectation for each row, just like I do it in this (NUnit) example?

The system under test here is the `Constraint` class that can have multiple ranges of valid integers. The test test the `NarrowDown` method that can make the valid ranges smaller based  on another constraint.

```
[TestFixture]
internal class ConstraintTests
{
    [Test]
    public void NarrowDown_Works()
    {
        RowTest_NarrowDown(
            new Range[] { new Range(0, 10), new Range(20, 30), new Range(40, 50) },
            new Range[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49) },
            new Range[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49) });

        RowTest_NarrowDown(
            new Range[] { new Range(0, 10), new Range(20, 30), new Range(40, 50), new Range(60, 70) },
            new Range[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49) },
            new Range[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49) });

        RowTest_NarrowDown(
            new Range[] { new Range(0, 10), new Range(20, 30), new Range(40, 50) },
            new Range[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49), new Range(60, 70) });
    }

    private static void RowTest_NarrowDown(IEnumerable<Range> sut, IEnumerable<Range> context)
    {
        Constraint constraint = new Constraint(sut);
        Constraint result = constraint.NarrowDown(new Constraint(context));
        Assert.That(result, Is.Null);
    }

    private static void RowTest_NarrowDown(IEnumerable<Range> sut, IEnumerable<Range> context, IEnumerable<Range> expected)
    {
        Constraint constraint = new Constraint(sut);
        Constraint result = constraint.NarrowDown(new Constraint(context));
        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(result.Bounds, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
    }
}
```

Comment: Each set of inputs should be an independent test. If the logic of multiple tests is identical sans the input-output, use "Parameterized Tests". NUnit uses attributes or a method that provides the different input sets to a parameterized test. Each set is executed/reported as a different test case by the test runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a data-driven approach with data factories (in NUnit-speak, they're called *test case sources*). This makes your tests a lot easier to read, understand, modify and maintain (or, more generally, a lot cleaner):

```
[TestFixture]
internal class ConstraintTests
{
    static object[] TwoRanges = 
    {
        new object[]
            {
                new[] { new Range(0, 10), new Range(20, 30), new Range(40, 50) },
                new[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49), new Range(60, 70) }
            }
    };

    static object[] ThreeRanges = 
    {
        new object[]
            {
                new[] { new Range(0, 10), new Range(20, 30), new Range(40, 50) },
                new[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49) },
                new[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49) }
            },
        new object[]
            {
                new[] { new Range(0, 10), new Range(20, 30), new Range(40, 50), new Range(60, 70) },
                new[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49) },
                new[] { new Range(1, 9), new Range(21, 29), new Range(41, 49) }
            }
    };

    [Test, TestCaseSource("TwoRanges")]
    public void NarrowDown_WhenCalledWithTwoRanges_GivesTheExpectedResult(IEnumerable<Range> sut, IEnumerable<Range> context)
    {
        Constraint constraint = new Constraint(sut);
        Constraint result = constraint.NarrowDown(new Constraint(context));
        Assert.That(result, Is.Null);
    }

    [Test, TestCaseSource("ThreeRanges")]
    public void NarrowDown_WhenCalledWithThreeRanges_GivesTheExpectedResult(IEnumerable<Range> sut, IEnumerable<Range> context, IEnumerable<Range> expected)
    {
        Constraint constraint = new Constraint(sut);
        Constraint result = constraint.NarrowDown(new Constraint(context));
        Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
        Assert.That(result.Bounds, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
    }
}
```

See how much simpler your test methods have become now? Also, this will make each set of data from the originating test case source run in a separate test, so the whole thing won't fail only because one set of data causes a failure. Remember: A test should assert only **one** thing.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

First, you could **improve the name** of your unit test `NarrowDown_Works` is extremely vague, and I can't tell what the class under test is supposed to be doing.

You have lots of assertions going on and lots of data, I can't tell what is important.  Try to **break your test into smaller tests** and it will be easier to name them as well.  If possible use **one assertion per test**.

Your construction of test data is quite complex, consider using **matchers** like [NHamcrest](https://github.com/grahamrhay/NHamcrest/wiki) to reduce the amount of assertion data you need instead of using `Is.EquivalentTo`.

You could also use a builder or factory constructors to to **make the initialization simpler** for the `Constraint` class simpler rather than passing in an array of `Ranges`.